# JS: || outside of if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand this code (check whether a string can be re-arranged to a palindrome) :

```
function canRearrangeToPalindrome(str){
    var letterCounts = {};
    var letter;
    var palindromeSum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        letter = str[i];
        letterCounts[letter] = letterCounts[letter] || 0;
        letterCounts[letter]++;
    }
    for (var letterCount in letterCounts) {
        palindromeSum += letterCounts[letterCount] % 2;
    }

    return palindromeSum < 2;
}
```

Could you explain line `letterCounts[letter] = letterCounts[letter] || 0;`
It's outside of `if` statement, how can we use `||` ? 
Thank you!

Comment: if there isn't a truthy value in letterCounts[letter] it will set it to 0

Comment: Same as `letterCounts[letter] ? letterCounts[letter] : 0`

Comment: Here is a test script that you can run in the console:

   `test = [0, 1];
    
    result = test[2] || 'This index does not exist.';`

On the first line, we define `test` as an array with 2 indices.

One the second line, we request the 3rd index of `test`, which doesn't exist.

Since there is no value for `test[2]`, the operation returns 'This index does not exist'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the index at `letter` in `letterCounts` has a falsy value then set the value at that index to `0`

Here is the MDN documentation for Falsy:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

If `letterCounts[letter]` has a value it will assign that value otherwise it will assign `0`.